# How to test a (java) fluent API?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, fluent

I'm building a java fluent API like this one

```
new Job().doFirst().doAfterFirst().thisOne();
new Job().doFirst().doAfterFirst().orThisOne();
```

I can do it by defining some classes / interfaces like

```
public class Job {
    DoAfterFirst doFirst();
}

public interface DoAfterFirst {
    FinishWith doAfterFirst();
}

public interface FinishWith {
    void thisOne();
    void orThisOne();
}
```

Because it is a DSL and not a `Builder`, I would like to tests the order of the methods. For example I would like to test that if I called `doAfterFirst()` I can now only call `thisOne()` and `orThisOne()`. I was thinking about something like (but I can successfully achieve that)

```
@Test
public void testDoAfterFirstChoice() {
    String expectedResults = new String[] {"thisOne","orThisOne"};
    assertTrue(new Job().doFirst().doAfterFirst().availableChoices().equals(expectedResults));
}
```

Currently I have junit tests to tests each of this method, but this tests are not able to check the order. I manually check that the order is right but I would like to write it as tests so I will be able to rerun them if I extend my DSL.

How should I test this point (the order) ? Is unit tests the right way to do it ? Are there some libraries to do it ?

**EDIT**

The aim of the tests is to validate the DSL. If the DSL is correct, I'm sure that after `doAfterFirst()` I will have `thisOne()` and `orThisOne()` (because the compiler will check that).

This example is simple, but most of the time DSL is larger with mandatory, optional and repeatable methods. In this case when you add a functionality to your DSL, you can broke some other rules. I want my tests to check that nothing is broken.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're wanting to sanity test your API from a business point of view. You could probably write a couple of (reflection based) helper methods to help

```
private void assertSequence(Class<? extends Job> jobType, String[] methods) {
   Class currentType = jobType;
   for (String methodName : methods) {
      try {
         Method method = currentType.getMethod(methodName);
         currentType = method.getReturnType();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Assert.fail(e.toString());
      }
   }
}

/**
 * @param expectedOptions The expected options after invoking the sequence of methods
 */
private void assertSequenceOptions(Class<? extends Job> jobType, String[] methods, String[] expectedOptions) {
   Class currentType = jobType;
   for (String methodName : methods) {
      try {
         Method method = currentType.getMethod(methodName);
         currentType = method.getReturnType();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Assert.fail(e.toString());
      }
   }
   Set<String> actualMethods = new HashSet<String>();
   for (Method method : currentType.getMethods()) {
      if (!Object.class.equals(method.getDeclaringClass()
             && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) 
      {
         actualMethods.add(method.getName());
      }
   }
   assertEquals(actualMethods, new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(expectedOptions)));
}
```

Usage

```
String[] sequence = { "doFirst", "doAfterFirst" };
String[] expectedOptions = { "thisOne","orThisOne" };
assertSequence(Job.class, sequence);
assertSequenceOptions(SpecialJob.class, sequence, expectedOptions);
```

Answer (score 4):

don't do it. the beauty of static languages is that compiler does a lot of testing for you. after `doAfterFirst()` you can call only `thisOne()` or `orThisOne()` because it's defined by the interface. and compiler will check it at each compilation. there is simply no other possibility your code compiles. what other order would you expect? are you afraid that someone will call `thisOne()` and later `doFirst()`? compiler won't allow that

instead test the result of your whole fluent DSL execution. check if code inside your builder is correct. but don't test the possible methods at each step

Comment: I tend to agree with this. You wouldn't write a unit test to catch a syntax error so why would you write a unit test to catch any other compile time error. Unit testing is for catching runtime errors.

Comment: I was not clear. I was thinking of this kind of tests to validate my DSL. If the DSL is right, at runtime everything will be ok. The example is really simple but I can also have optional, mandatory and repeatable methods. And sometimes when you add another method you break some rules.

Comment: you can't automatically validate if DSL is good for your business. you just have to be a good designer. All you can test is that if the code is doing what you want it to do (results and interactions)

Comment: can't you just have some tests that actually *use the DSL* and if you make breaking changes the tests *won't compile*?

Comment: @SamHolder I'm currently doing it. This is what I called _manually_ in my question. For example if I expect exactly two methods and a change "accidently" add a third one all the tests will success.

Comment: @piotrek I agree, be a good designer is a solution. But I will share this API and (maybe) not maintain it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write reflection-based tests (cf. [Lance Java's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632562/27358)) in a fluent style for your fluent API, you could tag your fluent API classes with a marker interface and use [AssertJ custom assertions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-custom-assertions.html):

#### Marker interface:

```
package myfluentapi;

interface MyFluentAPI {
    // marker interface for testing
}

class Job implements MyFluentAPI {
    DoAfterFirst doFirst() { /* ... */ }
}

interface DoAfterFirst extends MyFluentAPI {
    FinishWith doAfterFirst();
}

interface FinishWith extends MyFluentAPI {
    void thisOne();
    void orThisOne();
}
```

#### Test code:

```
import static myfluentapi.MyFluentAPIAssert.*;

public class JobTest {
    @Test
    public void doAfterFirstHasOnlyTwoChoices() {
        assertThat(new Job().doFirst().doAfterFirst())
          .hasOnlyChoices("thisOne", "orThisOne");
    }
}
```

#### Custom assertion class:

Note that I'm using the Java 8 Streams API to compare the lists of actual and expected methods, but you could just as easily make the comparisons procedurally (again cf. [Lance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632562/27358)) if you're not comfortable with the functional style.

```
import org.assertj.core.api.AbstractAssert;

public class MyFluentAPIAssert extends AbstractAssert<MyFluentAPIAssert, MyFluentAPI> {

    protected MyFluentAPIAssert(MyFluentAPI actual) {
        super(actual, MyFluentAPIAssert.class);
    }

    public static MyFluentAPIAssert assertThat(MyFluentAPI actual) {
        return new MyFluentAPIAssert(actual);
    }

    private Stream<String> getActualChoices() {
        return Arrays.asList(actual.getClass().getMethods()).stream()
                .filter((m) -> !Object.class.equals(m.getDeclaringClass()))
                .map(Method::getName);
    }

    public void hasChoices(String... choices) {
        Stream<String> actualChoices = getActualChoices();
        Stream<String> expectedChoices = Arrays.asList(choices).stream();

        Set<String> actualSet = actualChoices.collect(Collectors.toSet());
        String missing = expectedChoices
                .filter((choice) -> !actualSet.contains(choice))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        if (!missing.isEmpty()) {
            failWithMessage("Expected <%s> to have choices <%s>, but the following choices were missing: <%s>", actual.getClass().getName(), String.join(", ", choices), missing);
        }
    }

    public void hasOnlyChoices(String... choices) {
        hasChoices(choices); // first fail if any are missing

        Stream<String> actualChoices = getActualChoices();
        Stream<String> expectedChoices = Arrays.asList(choices).stream();

        Set<String> expectedSet = expectedChoices.collect(Collectors.toSet());
        String extra = actualChoices
                .filter((choice) -> !expectedSet.contains(choice))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        if (!extra.isEmpty()) {
            failWithMessage("Expected <%s> to only have choices <%s>, but found the following additional choices: <%s>", actual.getClass().getName(), String.join(", ", choices), extra);
        }
    }
}
```